# chaining uiviewcontroller delegates

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

i have a uivewcontroller (let's call it A) that loads uiviewcontroller (B) setting it up as a delegate which i use to close B and continue code on A. There is also a scenerio where B leads to another uiviewcontroller C (again with a delegate). When C is closed i use it's delegate to return to B but in this scenario i also want B to be immediately dismissed and the code to return to A. Now, B->A works, and C->B works but doing C->B->A fails at B with an error:
"attempt to dismiss modal view controller whose view does not currently appear" it appears to be trying to dismiss view C again.

Both viewcontrollers are being dismissed with this code (though the code sits in different uiviewcontrollers)

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Am I using delegates correctly for what i want, or should i be using a different process?

Code for option 1 (A->B, B<-A):

A -> B

```
scorer_turn *st = (scorer_turn *) segue.destinationViewController;
st.st_delegate=self;
st.league = _match.league;
st.match = _match;
st.leg = _leg;
st.set = _set;
```

B -> A

```
-(void)closeView{
[_st_delegate scorer_turn:self didFinish:YES];
}

-(void)scorer_turn:(scorer_turn *)controller didFinish:(BOOL)finish{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Code for option 2 (A->B, B->C, C->B->A):

as above plus:
B -> C

```
matchSummaryViewController *ms = (matchSummaryViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
ms.match = _match;
ms.oneScreen = NO;
ms.delegate = self;
[[segue destinationViewController] setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

C -> B, B -> A

in C:
    [_delegate matchSummaryViewController:self didFinish:YES];
in B:
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [_st_delegate scorer_turn:self didFinish:YES];
in A (this is where the error occurs):

```
-(void)scorer_turn:(scorer_turn *)controller didFinish:(BOOL)finish{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: A presents B -> delegate dismisses B presents C delegate dismisses C presents B delegate dismisses B ? is that what you are stating ? if so, it seems correct but toggling back and forth between modals is annoying for a user

Comment: Could you include more code? How do you call `dismissViewController...`

Comment: Not quite, two options: A presents B -> delegate dismisses B. Or A presents B -> presents C delegate dismisses C then delegate dismisses B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ViewController B is a modalViewController, and ViewController C is pushed onto the same modalViewController, then calling

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

should dismiss the entire modal view - as in, it'll dismiss C and skip B all-together (B wont even appear), which would cause problems if B tries to also call **dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion**: since there is no more modal view to dismiss.

Now, if you have some other set-up, such as B being a modal which, when pushing C, it actually dismisses itself and launches a new modal view (this would happen if you always use the **presentViewController:animated:completion** function), then you have other design problems - you shouldn't be swapping modal views like that, instead use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:C animated:YES]
```

to show the view and

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

to dismiss View C and return to View B.

This is assuming of course that you're using a navigationController to manage your views (which you typically should be doing).

If on the other hand you aren't using modal views at all, then **dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion**: isn't what you want to use at all.

Comment: They are all modalViewControllers, what I hadn't released was that i didn't need to dismiss them separately. So instead of trying to dismiss C from B, I go to A and dismiss from there. Thanks for your explanation.